# select link having href with a specific get variable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

in the example below - how to select the link having `c=ni`

```js
let a = 'c=ni';
let target = '...'; // select `alink` having `a` inside its href
//target.addClass('act');
```

```css
.act{background:orange;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class='alink' href='index.php?c=kb'>lorem</a>
<br>
<a class='alink' href='index.php?c=ni'>lorem</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Plain JS**

You could use `querySelector` with `*` wildcard

```js
let a = 'c=ni';
let target = document.querySelector(`a[href*='${a}']`)
target.classList.add('act');
```

```css
.act{background:orange;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class='alink' href='index.php?c=kb'>lorem</a>
<br>
<a class='alink' href='index.php?c=ni'>lorem</a>
```

**jQuery**

The query selector is the same, use `first()` to select one only

```js
let a = 'c=ni';
$(`a[href*='${a}']`).first().addClass('act')
```

```css
.act{background:orange;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class='alink' href='index.php?c=kb'>lorem</a>
<br>
<a class='alink' href='index.php?c=ni'>lorem</a>
```

Comment: Good answer. The 'attribute ends with' selector may be more useful here to prevent false positives though: `a[href$='${a}']`

Answer (score 2):

You can use attribute selectors. They can be used for javascript, jQuery or CSS. Read more about [Attribute selectors here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

```js
let target = $('.alink[href*="c=ni"]');
target.addClass('act');
```

```css
.act{background:orange;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class='alink' href='index.php?c=kb'>lorem</a>
<br>
<a class='alink' href='index.php?c=ni'>lorem</a>
```